# How to translate "tonight" meaning "this evening" and "this night"?

Tags: translation

English word "tonight" can have a meaning "this evening" and "this night" as well. I can translate into Japanese both of them as [今夜]{こんや}. But how to translate it into Japanese to mean exactly "this evening" (before midnight) and "this night" (I mean after midnight, for example at 1 AM)?

Comment: `"this night" (I mean after midnight`「今夜/今晩、日付が変わってから」とか・・

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weather report uses the following words:
夜遅く: from 9pm to midnight
未明: from midnight to 3am
明け方: from 3am to 6am

So you could say 今夜未明 to mean "this night after midnight".

http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/228567/meaning/m1u/%E5%A4%9C/
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/213462/meaning/m0u/%E6%9C%AA%E6%98%8E/
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/3055/meaning/m0u/

Answer (score 0):

I believe [今晩]{こん・ばん} encompasses both evening and night.  According to the Japanese dictionaries built-in to my macOS (大辞泉 and スーパー大辞林; not sure of the versions), 晩 has meanings of

> - [日暮]{ひ・ぐ}れ, [夕暮]{ゆう・ぐ}れ　→　sunset, dusk
> - [夕方]{ゆう・がた}　→　evening
> - 夜　→　night

Comment: Might be good to mention 今宵 as well.